# How to style only one child div?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code :

when i work on one div property all div are effected, suggest me an answer

Html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div>
    <img src="images/logo.jpg">
</div>
<div>
<img src="images/logo.jpg">
</div>
<div>
<img src="images/logo.jpg">
</div>
```

css

```
 #wrapper {
width: 80%;
height: 300px;
margin-left: 250px;
margin-top: 30px;
}
#wrapper div {
background: #c0bebe;
display: inline-block;
width: 27%;
height: 80%;
margin-left: 10px;
```

}

Comment: Yes it's how CSS works. `#wrapper div` will target all div inside the elements `#wrapper`. See http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: give the div a class or id and style that

Comment: add different `class` for each div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this : `#wrapper div`

In CSS means : "Affect this CSS to all `div` children of the element having the `wrapper` id."

---

**Some solutions to apply CSS to the wanted `div` :**

- **Selecting first child element**

If you only want the first child to get the CSS, for example, you should use : `#wrapper div:first-child`

**[W3SCHOOL](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)**

**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)**

---

- **Selecting one precise child element**

You can precise which child element you want : `#wrapper div:nth-child(2)`. To get the second `div`.

[**W3SCHOOL**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)**

---

- **Usign CSS class** (to style multiple `div`)

You also can use a class on the elements you want to style :

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="styledDiv">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="styledDiv">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.styledDiv {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/82NMg/1/)

---

- **Using CSS id** (must be unique, so to style one `div`)

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>
        <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/82NMg/)